# Joomla Virtuemart Credit card payment method redirect from bank issue

Tags: php, joomla, payment-gateway, virtuemart, payment-method

I'm new to Joomla but my task is to develop a payment method plugin for virtuemart which handles credit card payments. I could manage to send the user to the bank interface, I got the framework from the bank and test datas for cards. I must give a "backURL" parameter to the `$_REQUEST` global, the bank will redirect me to that url. I gave it the cart's url, but the bank automatically sets some extra arguments for the backurl. The basic cart url with random cart id is `index.php/cart?Itemid=486`. The bank send me back to this url: `cart?Itemid=486&paymentAnswer=true&posId=%2302299991&trasactionId=82085643863031898809897446845071`. This url shows me a 404 error. How can I handle these extra parameters in joomla? Is it template related? I'm using Joomla 2.5 with VurtueMart 3.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Joomla and more importantly what version of Virtuemart?

Answer (score 0):

On your web server is actived a ModSecurity, try to disable it and it will work. I had same problem